# I want store a specific number when achieving the condition in to a list Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to store 1 and -1 in a list when achieving the conditional wholesale

```
M1= ((data.GO> 0) & (data.GO.shift(1) < 0))*-1
M2= ((data.GO< 0) & (data.GO.shift(1) > 0))*1
data['direction'] =M1+M2

if  data['direction'].iloc[0] ==-1:
    MS= -1
if  data['direction'].iloc[0] ==1:
    MS=1
```

I want to store value `MS`

Explain more about what I want

[image]

I am new to programming sorry if there are errors in the code

Comment: I explained what I want is the value storage (MS) and The expected result is in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want MS as a list, declare a empty list MS in front of your code `MS = []` 
After your if/else statements append the values to your list `MS.append(-1)` or `MS.append(1)`

It will give you a list [1,-1,1,1,-1 ...... ]